# Was #Alive made before or after the Coronavirus outbreak?

Tags: alive

I am wondering if the Korean movie *#Alive* was somehow affected by the pandemic. The theme of the movie is isolation, so I wonder if this theme is somehow supposed to be related to the lockdown and if I can look at this movie and analyze it as a commentary on the quarantine. But if the movie was written and shot before the pandemic, then it is all just a coincidence. So, was *#Alive* made before or after the Coronavirus outbreak began?

Comment: Did you check the film's [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alive_(2020_film)#Production)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that the casting started in July 2019, and that COVID-19 wasn't known about until late November 2019, I'd say the script was written independent of COVID and has nothing to do with it.

Comment: conspiracy theorist: maybe they knew..we didn't. but maybe they just did